# Android SDK Windows Failed to execute Android.bat

Tags: android

The title might sound slightly "nubbish" but i assure you it is not, i am completely aware of 90% of systax commands in cmd i am able to install and uninstall .apk's via adb however this particular nitch keeps setting me back!  I have been working on Android SDK for a week or more now and consistently i am presented with the same issue.

http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/4492/wtfmanzm.jpg

Initially i get my first instance of my Android emulator to run by double clicking SDK Manager or AVD Manager where i am able to start my emulator.  Everything loads and runs accordingly, then like clockwork the first instance is the only instance i am ever able to open!  After this if i close this particular instance of my android emulator and attempt to re-open the above picture is what i am presented with every single time.  My PATH certainly isn't the issue, i am able to start and kill server via cmd.  However i have at present been unable to close my emulator and re-open it with success.  Without creating a restore point just before opening it for the first time then having to restore to allow myself to open my emulator again.  SURELY this is not how this is suppose to work i must be missing one little step that fixes this problem does anyone have a clue why this is happening and what i must do to fix this?

Comment: In my case the issue was that the sdk manager was in the wrong location and thus not able to locate, as they error said, "tools\android.bat". Could you check if the android.bat is located in tools. and if not, move it there.

Answer (score 7):

Copy the "AVD Manager.exe" and "SDK Manager.exe" from

```
SDK_ROOT_FOLDER/tools/lib/
```

into

```
SDK_ROOT_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to your user home folder (like C:\Users\Psych0) and remove the ".android" folder.
Now you should be able to launch the AVD Manager again from the Eclipse menu.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed that by copying "SDK Manager.exe" file from my folder c:\dev\Android\sdk\tools\lib\ into folder c:\Android\sdk\ and running it from there. while using process monitor it's clear that the exe is searching for the file in many places just not where it's expected when you run it from the \lib\ folder where it must be by accident. (I used the Android SDK bundle downloaded just a few days ago)

Answer (score 1):

Change PATH variable from 
control panel > Advance system setting > advanced tab > enviroment variable 
to jdk e.g C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin

and delete .android folder from e,g C:\Users\AliG
In my case it works :)

Answer (score 1):

easily put avd manager to the path `...\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk`. because it should open tools folder and tools folder is in the path i said. the strange thing is why developers didn't put avd manager in the right path themselves!!!

Comment: @Hamad He's not asking. He's telling. You're comment has no significance at all!

Answer (score 0):

ya, that is strange, after installation, we have to move the avdmanager.exe to make the emulator first happen as the video -- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLEYAj737Pg

I put the avd...exe here

```
C:\andriodSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk
```

sometime, there is also instruction (somewhere) that android directory have to be NO SPACE in folder name, so I did not put it in desktop or download folder this time BEFORE I run the SDK manager

when I click add NEW button for the 1 emulator to be NEW
it still take some time when I press [OK]-- some waiting time here

but after a while , then click [start]- [launch] in AVD, it works !!  -- take 3 minutes to launch (people say do not close it once launch, reuse it]

hope that 2nd time [start] there is a progress bar

but NO EMULATOR pop up after the progress bar finish , I wait for 10 minute already

i.e. still NO emulator

THEN I try out this
use android 2.1 platform

randomly choose a device at the bottom (older phone device)

at least, the emulator come up -- but no function -- just black screen  {around 4 minutes to wait for the black screen to be gone)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you take latest update of eclipse & SDK then

close eclipse first

You get tools_r22.6.3-windows.rar file 
at sdk_root_folder/temp/

extract it 
you will get tools folder just copy that in to your
sdk_root_folder/tools/

then restart eclipse

I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i got same error,it occurred in my system because the tools folder was empty. but i've backup of tools folder so i just copy and paste the contents of tools folder in ../sdk/tools.  then restart eclipse . It solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I has this problem, and I do this things:

1. From `sdk path` rename `tools` file to `tools-Backup`.
2. Go to `sdk path\temp`.
3. You will see archive file open it.
4. Now you must see the `tools` file inside it extract it in `sdk path`.

**And now it should work with you just run `SDK Manager.exe` and you will see it !**