# How to fix "Error - Failed to execute tools\android.bat, error 2 " in Android?

Tags: android

When i click on AVD Manager, i am getting an error as in the screenshot below.

Referred to the following links. But none of the solution works for me.

[Failed to execute tools\android.bat: solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015587/failed-to-execute-tools-android-bat-solution)

[Android SDK Windows Failed to execute Android.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513023/android-sdk-windows-failed-to-execute-android-bat)

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33538/android-sdk-cant-find-android-bat

In Tools -> Lib Folder i have my AVD Manager.

In Tools -> i have android.bat

I tried the following options and it did not work.

1. Copied Android SDK Manager in Lib folder and clicked on AVD Manager. Got the same error.
2. Copied AVD Manager to Tools folder and clicked AVD Manager. Got the same error.

Please find below the error screenshot.

[image]

Kindly let me know if any thoughts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753240/avd-manager-cant-find-tools-android-bat-even-though-its-there?rq=1 maybe

Comment: got the same crappy message. Lame android developers, damn...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My `android.bat` file was missing when updating the particular SDK package and my computer suddenly shut down. Thus, my tools folder became empty.

[image]

You can recover your `android.bat` file from **temp** folder

[image]

1. Manually unzip **tools_r23.05-windows** or any **tool_rXX.zip** file (red color)
2. Get a folder called **tools** (orange color)
3. Copy **all** the file in this folder to the original `tools` folder (outside temp folder, e.g. D:\android-sdk\tools)

In my case, the problem was solved this way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awsome! Might have got corrupted when my update stopped midway. Thanks @yean

Comment: Thanks. This happened to me with Visual Studio 2015 Preview and Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem. This happened while updating android studio and my laptop shut down suddenly.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.. !

Comment: If you don't have these zipfiles like in my case I suggest [reinstalling SDK tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) instead of manually adding tool directories.

Comment: I have to do this procedure whenever attempting to update tools. I get a 'can't move folder' error message then lose all tools after update attempt. I had to do the same thing after each tools update attempt in eclipse.

Comment: A similar solution given years ago for eclipse eventually got hundreds of up votes, nice work.

Answer (score 8):

Please check your COMSPEC environment variable (intuitive, I know).

There are apparently some programs that modify this, which in turn break these Android tools (and presumably other programs that rely on .bat files as well).

To check this, in a command window, type

> echo %COMSPEC%

The resulting value should probably be `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

If you have multiple exes jammed in there, or if the variable ends with a semicolon, you've got a broken COMSPEC variable. If so, please edit your system's environment variables and fix it, setting it to the cmd.exe path above.

Comment: This answer Solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I found where it's come from. I know it's a 2 year question, but the problem still remain the same for some people.

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat
```

It will happen when we re-install android studio for some reasons. I even re-installed it 4 times. Problem came at the first time I re-installed. I tried to re-install again and again but the problem remain the same.

Finally I open C:\Users\Hp\AppData that actually hidden. And in the next folder \local\Android\Sdk, now I found some folder Sdk, Sdk1, Sdk2, and Sdk3.

Now I remember, as I re-installed it 4 times, that's why I have four folders. I remove ( not actually remove, but rename it with additional XX at the end of folder name) Sdk folder and change Sdk3 to Sdk. Now everything is working fine.

Why? because my last re-install create Sdk3 folder that contain android.bat required for the main program where no more exist in the first Sdk folder.

Before I got this as well :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

And now it's missing and the problem is solved.

If you happen got the same problem with me. hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying this file  [SDK HOME]\tools\android.bat

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe= JAVA PATH\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

*
JAVA PATH is in your java sdk folder

and delete these two lines:

```
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

more here: [Issue 42896:    SDK Manager fails to open](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42896)

Comment: My android.bat doesn't contain "rem check".

Answer (score 0):

I have a x86 system (not x86_64).

in tools\lib\find_jave.bat I replaced:

```
  find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

With:

```
  rem find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
  set arch_ext=32
```

Then when android.bat runs, it prints:

```
  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Yet it DOES run the SDK manager.

I suspect the 'find' line is broken. If you have a 64 bit system, try setting arch_ext to 64 and test that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case.Android root folder was readonly.
-->Remove readonly tick

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and downloaded tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip file. I think this problem caused on updating tools. I deleted tools to update but this error occured when I installed. Be careful updating.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to copy those " SDK Manager.exe " and "AVD Manager.exe" to the SDK root folder, I needed to copy them to C:\android-sdk\ form Lib Folder, this is because, SDK Manager.exe and AVD Manager.exe are looking for tools

Comment: This question was answered 3 years ago. What value does your answer bring?

Comment: Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Also, this question is 4 years old, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My situation: Right after installing Android support into Visual Studio, the "Open Android Emulator Manager (AVD)" button was broken and running *C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\AVD Manager.exe* produces the error shown by the OP. The screenshot in yean's answer shows an android-sdk folder that contains AVD Manager.exe, but my android-sdk folder did not contain any files (only folders).

Crazy as it sounds, simply copying **AVD Manager.exe** from **android-sdk\tools\lib** to **android-sdk** fixes both problems. (I couldn't create an API-18 arm emulator but API-19 worked.)

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't working for me as I did not have this bat file nor the tools directory at all.  And my temp directory did not have any zipped tools directory, so could not just replace.

MS suggested doing repair install

1. Open the Windows Programs and Features Control Panel.
2. Right click the relevant Microsoft Visual Studio entry, and select
   Change
3. Click the Repair button in the Visual Studio dialog that opens.

That resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Happened several times on my environment. @Mahmood and @Qwertie solutions did help, until today.

Banged my head the whole afternoon searching & trying many solutions... finally [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610759/488666) unlocked the situation:

**Remove hidden directory `C:\Users\{yourUserName}\.android`**

Answer (score -2):

Please copy the `AVD Manager. Exe` to the `SDK Manager. Exe`'s directory which is the root directory of the SDK.

Answer (score -2):

Check that if the tools folder is missing in /sdk folder. If so, just unzip again from the zip package to the /sdk folder again. It works like charm for my case.

cheers.

i think it occurs when i accidentally hit delete packages button.